# Homotopy Kan extensions, formally coherent functors and derived Schlessinger criterion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a finite field. Denote by $discArt_k$ the category of Artinian rings with residue field $k$ and $Art_k$ the category of Artinian simplicial rings. Consider a functor $\mathcal{F}:disArt_k\rightarrow sSets$, such that $\mathcal{F}(k)$ is contractible.  Now we can extend this functor along $disArt_k\rightarrow Art_k$ via homotopy Kan extension to a functor
$$hom\mathcal{F}:Art_k\rightarrow sSets.$$
By construction, this functor preserves homotopy equivalences and is reduced. One of the conditions in the derived Schlessinger criterion for $hom\mathcal{F}$ to be pro-representable is that it is reduced, is homotopy invariant and preserves homotopy pullback. So it natural to ask when $hom\mathcal{F}$ preserves pullbacks.

Is it necessary that $\mathcal{F}$ respects pullbacks? I'm asking because I'm studying a functor $\mathcal{F}$ which I suspect is not (pro-)representable, but would hope that $hom\mathcal{F}$ might be. Is this sensible? The "geometric" hope behind this that the "non-transverse" intersection of affine schemes might not be affine, but is representable by a derived scheme.

Comment: Pullbacks of rings correspond to gluing, not intersecting. The inclusion $disArt_k \subset Art_k$ preserves pullbacks, so yes, it is necessary that $\mathcal F$ preserves pullbacks. In fact, if $hom\mathcal F$ is pro-representable by $(A_i)$, then $\mathcal F$ is pro-representable by $(\pi_0 A_i)$.